# inline styling changes when custom component is used

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have an Ionic app which has a permanent header on all pages with tabs.

```
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      <span>
        Home
      </span>
      <button ion-button icon-only small round [navPush]="createHuntsPage" ><ion-icon item-right name="add"></ion-icon></button>
      <button ion-button icon-only small round [navPush]="profilePage" ><ion-icon item-right name="person"></ion-icon></button>
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>
```

Instead of that I created a custom component which has this same template and added it as with selector `my-header`.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-header',
  templateUrl: 'header.html'
})
export class HeaderComponent {
  constructor() {  }
}
```

and i add ,`<my-header>` in my template. Everything works fine except for a small issue. The first approach added an inline style attribute which is missing when I use custom component.

> Without custom component

```
<div class="scroll-content" style="margin-top: 56px; margin-bottom: 56px;">
```

> With custom component

```
<div class="scroll-content" style="margin-bottom: 56px;">
```

Why is this happening ? Is there any issues that can come with this approach ? I can fix this by adding `margin-top: 56px;` But I would like to know why this is happening? I have the tab on the bottom , if that has some thing to do with this.